# using sql to determine rate of change in data set

Tags: sql

Let's say i have a table with the following data:

day1 item1 30
day1 item2 25
day1 item3 27
day2 item1 30
day2 item2 30
day2 item3 20
...
dayN item1 20

How would I structure a query that can give me the rate of change for each item on a daily basis.

day1 item1 rateOfChange:0
day1 item2 rateOfChange:-1
day1 item3 rateOfChange:5
day2 item1 rateOfChange:0
day2 item2 rateOfChange:2

My inital thought (without knowing sql too well), would be to loop through each day, and have a subquery that checks for the day before for each item and does a difference?

Thanks

Comment: Sounds like something which is easier to do in a client application..

Comment: Which DBMS? (I ask because there are slightly smarter ways to do it in PostgreSQL or Oracle, for example, than in MySQL.) Also -- does your table really contain values like `'day1'` and `'day2'` and so on? If so, it sounds like we'd have to extract the numbers from those values?

Comment: Where are you getting 0,-1,5,0,2 from?

Comment: LAG functions ftw (if your engine supports it)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you table was called datatable with a day,item and value integer columns, this might do it

```
SELECT t1.day, t1.item, (t2.value - t1.value) as rate
FROM datatable t1
INNER JOIN datatable t2
ON t1.item = t2.item 
AND t1.day + 1 = t2.day
```

Comment: Just a note: This works if you don't want a record for the last day that a particular item is on. If you only have a record for that item for one day, then this won't return any rows for that item at all. If you left join to `t2`, then you'll get a row for every day for each item and have `NULL` for `rate` if it is the last day.

Comment: @JeremyPridemore Yup, it depends what results makes more sense for your needs. However if you do want a row for every day(using the left join), you'll have to also change how the rate is calculated to handle the NULL value for t2.value.

Answer (score 5):

A standard SQL solution which works on most modern DBMS

```
SELECT day, 
       item, 
       value, 
       value - lag(value) over (partition by item order by day) as diff_to_prev
FROM your_table
ORDER by day, item
```

Comment: Most modern DBMS --> SQL 2012+

Comment: @ScottLenart: this was introduced in the SQL:2006 standard, not 2012

Comment: Not according to any article I find. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/lag-transact-sql

Comment: @ScottLenart: that link refers to a product called "SQL Server", **not** to the SQL **standard** called SQL:2006