# RUBY CSV Calculate Return

Tags: ruby, csv

I am trying to calculate 2 days return for a list of companies. All information are saved in a CSV. The structure is like this: first column is company name, second is the date, the third is price, the forth column is return = p(t+2)/p(t).

(1) The CSV is 1.8G. Using "CSV.each_with_index.." is very slow. If I use "CSV.foreach", it doesn't let me to find the price in two days.

(2) There are missing values in price. So even if I use CSV.each_with_index, i + 2 may not identify the right date.

Thanks for your help.

Input:

```
[
    ['a', '2014-6-1', '1'],
    ['a', '2014-6-2', '2'],
    ['a', '2014-6-4', '3'],
    ['a', '2014-6-5', '4'],
    ['b', '2014-6-1', '1'],
    ['b', '2014-6-2', '2'],
    ['b', '2014-6-3', '3'],
    ['b', '2014-6-4', '4'],
    ['b', '2014-6-5', '5']

]
```

output:

```
[
    ['a', '2014-6-1', '1', ''],     # Missing because no 2014-6-3 price for a
    ['a', '2014-6-2', '2', '1.5'],  # p(a2014-6-4)/p(a2014-6-2) = 1.5
    ['a', '2014-6-4', '3', ''],     # Missing because no 2014-6-6 price
    ['a', '2014-6-5', '4', ''],     # Missing because no 2014-6-7 price
    ['b', '2014-6-1', '1', '3'],
    ['b', '2014-6-2', '2', '2'],
    ['b', '2014-6-3', '3', '1.7'],
    ['b', '2014-6-4', '4', ''],
    ['b', '2014-6-5', '5', '']

]
```

The logic I have in mind is as below. It is the same as the logic in the first comment. I haven't coded the second part as I am not sure what is a good way to merge a big CSV with itself in ruby. I also thought about searching the nth business day in following observations. But I want to avoid to use each_with_index as the CSV is very big. I don't know how to implement this logic in ruby.

(1) Calculate the nth business day after a date
(2) Merge the dataset with itself so I have the price on nth business day

```
require 'csv'
require 'business_time'
# 30/60/90/365 business days 
# cdate ncusip prc permno firm

csvIn   = 'in.csv'
csvOut  = 'out.csv'

csv = CSV.open(csvOut, "w")
csv << ['cdate', 'ncusip', 'prc', 'permon', 'firm', 'day60']


CSV.foreach(csvIn, :headers => true) do |row|
    current_date = Time.parse(row['cdate'])
    day60 = 42.business_days.after(current_date)
    csv << [row['cdate'], row['ncusip'], row['prc'], row['permno'], row['firm'], day60]

end


csv.close
```

Comment: Why not put this into a RDBMS and calculate using a solution like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9880175/using-sql-to-determine-rate-of-change-in-data-set

Comment: can you post on your code you have done so far? And what's the logic when there is some missing date? I coulden't figur out how is 1.3 came from.

Comment: The reason that I don't use database is that i only started to learn it this week :D. I am using POSTGRESQL and tried the codes in the first comment. Got an error "schema "t1" does not exist".

Comment: Also, if I have a missing date I will like to return to the missing value.

Comment: Suggestion: 1) Supply the define of the 4th output column. 2) Explain the logic of every output data by adding comments after each row. 3) The performance mainly related to your logic, CVS or RDBMS relates something about the implement detail only.

Comment: Post on your code, if there are some better solutions, we could compare the difference of performance.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60747/discussion-between-jxu-and-jaugar-chang).

Comment: @JaugarChang I posted what I have so far.

Comment: Consider constructing an enumerator from `CSV::foreach`, so that you could use [Enumerator#next](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerator.html#method-i-next) and [Enumerator#peek](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Enumerator.html#method-i-next), which would avoid the need for `each_with_index`, which is quite slow. `next` or `peek` will raise a `StopInteration` exception if the enumerator is at the end. If you iterate with [Kernel#loop](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Kernel.html), `loop` will handle `StopIteration` by breaking the loop. (cont.)

Comment: I understand that `CSV#foreach` will soon return an enumerator (Ruby 2.1.x). In the meantime, have a look at [this article](http://www.sitepoint.com/guide-ruby-csv-library-part-2/) by Darko Gjorgjievski. If you search for "Avdi" you'll find a way to construct an enumerator to step through the file.  One other point: had you considered maintaining a hash that maps string dates into string dates two days later, to eliminate the need to create and manipulate date objects? @JaugarChang may be willing add some benchmarks if you think either either of these ideas may have merit.

Comment: @CarySwoveland quite agree with you, I raised another issue about [*parsing string to Date*](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25760658/3630826), but I'm not satisfied with what I've done so far. Wish you could help me to improve that solution. Thanks in advance!

Comment: @JaugarChang, I'd be happy to help, if I can. I'll look at it more closely tomorrow. My email is at my profile if you wish to write directly, or we could chat.

Comment: @CarySwoveland Thanks. Will check out the article.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your code lead into some new requirements such as finding `nth business day`, but they are not clearly defined in the question, maybe more proper way is to open another question about "quickest way of finding nth business day in ruby" .

So let's only foucus on the requiment you commented in the result sample.

### Main points of the requirement:

- read a large csv file, with date formatted string in it
- for each day find price in n days after (n=2) in one group
- for each day's record append a ratio calculated by two days price, if there is no price after n days, leave it blank

### Basic Benchmark:

With the sample data repeated by 45,000 times, I got a 10MB csv file of 360,000 records in it.

My first thought is to generate a Buffer class to buffer the records that haven't met the next n days record yet. When push a new record to the buffer, the buffer will shift out all the records that is n days before the new record.

But I need to know some basic operations' processing time maybe used in this implementation, then I can figure out the lower limit of total processing time by choosing more efficient operations:

1. convert date formatted string to date at least 360,000 times
2. compare two days for 360,000 times
3. get the date that is n days after another date for 360,000 times
4. calculate the days between two dates for 360,000 times
5. compare two dates stored in an array of arrays for 360,000 times
6. push a row into buffer and shift out for 360,000 times
7. append a ratio or empty string to every record for 360,000 times

And I was heard that CSV is a very unefficient way , so I will compare two file parsing proccesing time too:

1. using CSV.foreach to read csv file row by row, and parse them into an array
2. using IO.read to read csv file into a string at once, and split the string into an array

**Basic benchmark scripts:**

```
require 'csv'
require 'benchmark'

Benchmark.bm{|x|
  epoch=Date.new(1970,1,1)
  date1=Date.today
  date2=Date.today.next
  i1=1
  i2=200000
  date_str='2014-6-1'
  a = [[1,2,4,date2],2,[1,2,4,date1]]
  #  1. convert date formatted string to date at least 360,000 times
  x.report("1.string2date"){
    360000.times{Date.strptime(date_str,"%Y-%m-%d")}
  }
  #  2. compare two days for 360,000 times
  x.report("2.DateCompare"){
    360000.times{date2>=date1}
  }
  #  3. get the date that is n days after another date for 360,000 times
  x.report("3.DateAdd2   "){
    360000.times{date1 + 2}
  }
  #  4. calculate the days between two dates for 360,000 times
  x.report("4.Date Differ"){
    360000.times{date2-date1}
  }
  #  5. compare two dates stored in an array of arrays for 360,000 times 
  x.report("5.ArrDateComp"){
    360000.times{ a.last[3] > a.first[3]}
  }
  #  6. push a row into buffer and shift out for 360,000 times 
  x.report("6.array shift"){
    360000.times{ a<<[1,2,3]; a.shift}
  }
  #  7. append a ratio or empty string to every record for 360,000 times 
  x.report("7.Add Ratio  "){
    360000.times{ res << (['1','2014-6-1',"3"]<< (2==2 ? (3.to_f/2.to_f).round(2) : "" ))}
  }

  x.report('CSVparse    '){
    CSV.foreach("data.csv"){|row| 
    }
  }
  x.report('IOread      '){
  data = IO.read("data.csv").split.inject([]){|memo,o| memo << o.split(',')}.each{|x| }
  }
}
```

**The result:**

```
                   user     system      total        real
1.string2date  0.827000   0.000000   0.827000 (  0.820001)
2.DateCompare  0.078000   0.000000   0.078000 (  0.070000)
3.DateAdd2     0.109000   0.000000   0.109000 (  0.110000)
4.Date Differ  0.359000   0.000000   0.359000 (  0.360000)
5.ArrDateComp  0.109000   0.000000   0.109000 (  0.110001)
6.array shift  0.094000   0.000000   0.094000 (  0.090000)
7.Add Ratio    0.530000   0.000000   0.530000 (  0.530000)
 CSVparse      2.902000   0.016000   2.918000 (  2.910005)
 IOread        0.515000   0.015000   0.530000 (  0.540000)
```

**Analyze the result**

- Transfer date formatted string to date is the slowest operation of all those operations, so it should be used at file parsing procedure, to ensure that the operation of transfering string to date will be executed only once for every record.
- Compare two dates is about 7 times faster than calculate the days between two dates, so I'll store the date after n days instead of store an integer of the days since epoch date in the buffer.
- The total proccessing time at least includes 1,2,3,5,6,7 those parts. So the lower limit of the estimate proccessing time should be 1.75 seconds. There are some overheads not included.
- With CSV parsing the lower limit would be 4.24 seconds.
- With IO#read and split the lower limit would be 2.262 seconds.

### The implementation of Buffer Class and push method

```
class Buff
  def initialize
    @buff=[]
    @epoch = Date.new(1970,1,1)
    @n=2
  end
  def push_date( row ) 
    # store buff with two date value appended, ["a", "2014-6-1", "1",  #<Date: 2014-06-01 ((2456908j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>,#<Date: 2014-06-03 ((2456908j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>]
    # the last element of date is n days after the record's date 
    res = []
    @buff << (row << (row[3] + @n) )
    while (@buff.last[3] >= @buff.first[4] || row[0] != @buff.first[0])
      v = (@buff.last[3] == @buff.first[4] && row[0] == @buff.first[0] ? (row[2].to_f/@buff.first[2].to_f).round(2) : "")
      res <<(@buff.shift[0..2]<< v)
    end
    return res
  end

  def tails
    @buff.inject([]) {|res,x|  res << (x[0..2]<< "")}
  end
  def clear
    @buff=[]
  end
end
```

### Benchmark

```
buff=Buff.new
res=[]
Benchmark.bm{|x|
  buff.clear
  res = []
  x.report("CSVdate"){
    CSV.foreach("data.csv"){|row| 
      buff.push_date(row << Date.strptime(row[1],"%Y-%m-%d")).each{|x| res << x}
    }
    buff.tails.each{|x| res << x}
  }

  buff.clear
  res = []
  x.report("IOdate"){
    IO.read("data.csv").split.inject([]){|memo,o| memo << o.split(',')}.each {|row| 
      buff.push_date(row << Date.strptime(row[1],"%Y-%m-%d")).each{|x| res << x}
    }
    buff.tails.each{|x| res << x}
  }

}
puts "output result count:#{res.size}"
puts "Here is the fist 12 sample outputs:"
res[0..11].each{|x| puts x.to_s}
```

**Result**

```
             user     system      total        real
CSVdate  6.411000   0.047000   6.458000 (  6.500009)
IOdate   3.557000   0.109000   3.666000 (  3.710005)

output result count:360000
Here is the fist 12 sample outputs:
["a", "2014-6-1", "1", ""]
["a", "2014-6-2", "2", 1.5]
["a", "2014-6-4", "3", ""]
["a", "2014-6-5", "4", ""]
["b", "2014-6-1", "1", 3.0]
["b", "2014-6-2", "2", 2.0]
["b", "2014-6-3", "3", 1.67]
["b", "2014-6-4", "4", ""]
["b", "2014-6-5", "5", ""]
["a", "2014-6-1", "1", ""]
["a", "2014-6-2", "2", 1.5]
["a", "2014-6-4", "3", ""]
```

**Conclusion**

- The real proccesing time is 3.557 seconds, it's about 57% slower than the estimated lower limit , but there are still some overheads not considerd.
- The CSV version is 2 times slower than the IO#read version.
- We should read the input file block by block with IO#read to prevent insufficient memory error.
- It must have some space to tuning.

**UPDATE1:**

### Tuning

More faster push by changeing the order of group compare and date compare:

```
class Buff
  def push_fast( row ) 
    # store buff with two date value appended, ["a", "2014-6-1", "1",  #<Date: 2014-06-01 ((2456908j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>,#<Date: 2014-06-03 ((2456908j,0s,0n),+0s,2299161j)>]
    # the last element of date is n days after the record's date 
    res = []
    row << (row[3] + @n) 
    # change the order of the two compares, can reduce the counts of date compares
    while @buff.first && (row[0] != @buff.first[0] || row[3] >= @buff.first[4] )
      v = (row[0] == @buff.first[0] && row[3] == @buff.first[4] ? (row[2].to_f/@buff.first[2].to_f).round(2) : "")
      res <<(@buff.shift[0..2]<< v)
    end
    @buff << row
    return res
  end
end
```

**Benchmark result**

```
            user     system      total        real
IOdate  3.806000   0.031000   3.837000 (  3.830005)
IOfast  3.323000   0.062000   3.385000 (  3.390005)
```

Can get 0.480 seconds promotion. Saving many date compare time by compare group first, if group changes, shift out all buffer records out without date compare.

Comment: Very nice.  I did not know about the benchmark library before. Thanks.

Comment: I simplified the question in the initial post and did think the searching for the nth business day should be raised in a different post. Thanks a lot for the detailed response. You demonstrated a good way to look for efficient method.

Answer (score 0):

Here is another possibility:

1. Perform a simple read into array, either using CSV or IO as Jaugar suggests.
2. Create a hash of ids and dates
3. Iterate over the input array and find date+2 in the hash.
4. Output the calculation

Assuming you have an array named input as you defined above, it would look something like this:

```
# convert.rb
require 'date'

class Convert
  attr_reader :dates_hash
  def initialize
    @input_array = []  
    @dates_hash = {}
    @n = 2
    @date_converter = {}
  end

  def add_to_hash(row)
    # create a hash of ids, dates and values, like this:
    # {"a"=>{#Date: 2014-6-1 => 1, #Date: 2014-6-4 => 2} ... etc.}
    id    = row[0]
    date  = to_date(row[1])
    value = row[2].to_i
    # Merge using a block, so that for a given id (like "a"), the inner hashes
    # append rather than replace each other
    @dates_hash.merge!( { id => { date => value } } ) do |key, x, y|
      x.merge(y) 
    end  
  end

  def input(input_array)
    output = input_array.map do |row| 
      id    = row[0]
      date  = to_date(row[1])
      value = row[2]
      #create a row of output with id, date, original value, and modified price
      #set variable date2 to the date + @n value.  If a exists, do the calculation
      row[0..2] <<  ( (date2 = @dates_hash[id][date+@n] ) ? date2/value.to_f : '') 
    end
  end

  def to_date(date)
    # convert to Date and memoize
    if converted_date = @date_converter[date]
      converted_date
    else
      @date_converter[date] = Date.parse(date)
    end
  end
end
```

I followed Jaugar's example and benchmarked as follows:

```
require 'csv'
require 'benchmark'
require './convert'
buff=[]
output = []
Benchmark.bm{|x|
  x.report("convert with csv"){
    converter = Convert.new()
    CSV.foreach("data.csv") do |row|
      buff << row
      converter.add_to_hash(row)
    end 
    output = converter.input(buff)
  }
  x.report("convert with IO"){
    converter = Convert.new()
    IO.readlines("data.csv").map{|row| row.split(',')}.each do |row|
      buff << row
      converter.add_to_hash(row)
    end
    output = converter.input(buff)
  }
}
puts "Here is the first 12 sample outputs:"
output[0..11].each{|x| puts x.to_s}
```

Jagaur's benchmark on my computer was:

```
       user     system      total        real
CSVdate 11.270000   0.020000  11.290000 ( 11.302404)
IOdate  8.740000   0.020000   8.760000 (  8.756997)
```

My benchmark was:

```
       user     system      total        real
convert with csv 10.450000   0.090000  10.540000 ( 10.546727)
convert with IO 12.850000   0.120000  12.970000 ( 12.972962)

["a", " 2014-6-1", " 1", ""]
["a", " 2014-6-2", " 2", 1.5]
["a", " 2014-6-4", " 3", ""]
["a", " 2014-6-5", " 4", ""]
["b", " 2014-6-1", " 1", 3.0]
["b", " 2014-6-2", " 2", 2.0]
["b", " 2014-6-3", " 3", 1.6666666666666667]
["b", " 2014-6-4", " 4", ""]
["b", " 2014-6-5", " 5", ""]
["a", " 2014-6-1", " 1", ""]
["a", " 2014-6-2", " 2", 1.5]
["a", " 2014-6-4", " 3", ""]
```

Not sure why my IO is slower, but it's within a similar range.  My hash wound up being very small just because the data in the csv constantly repeats itself.  Not sure how performance would be in a more realistic situation with a larger hash.  Should not degrade terribly as lookups on hashes are pretty efficient.